# How to access teams files/folders of guest user via graph api

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, httpclient, microsoft-teams, graph-explorer

Getting all the files/folders from the specific MSTeam channel.
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{Userid/UPN}/drives/{Drive id}/items/{ID}/children"

by using the above API I am able to get all the files and folders but it is only working for the owner and members but while trying to make the same call by passing GUEST user id it throws the below error.

{
"error": {
"code": "ResourceNotFound",
"message": "User's mysite not found.",
"innerError": {
"date": "2022-05-02T12:21:33",
"request-id": "78c5aaeb-2422-4c4f-a19c-54eb481e7ac5",
"client-request-id": "378eec9c-2b2e-bb71-dr6e-8f7de1ee7wedf"
}
}
}

Is there any way to get files/folder from a specific MS Team Channel by passing userid/UPN of guest user.

Comment: Why are you going via the /users path, instead of to the drive directly? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: hi @HiltonGiesenow so basically our requirement was to get files/folder of a specific user

Comment: @KrishnareddyChinthireddy - We are checking this internally. We will inform you once we have any update.

Comment: I'm confused. You say in your question you want 'files/folder from a specific MS Team Channel', but here you're saying you want the files/folders only for a specific user. Please clarify

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow yes our requirement is to get the specific user's files/folder he/she has access to in a specific MsTeam channel, consider one user have access to 3 ms team channels but i need to get  files/folders from a specific channel of that user which he/she has access.

Comment: @KrishnareddyChinthireddy - Could you please refer below doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get-filesfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http